# why does adapter.invalidate doesn't force redrawing new list?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have this code:

```
if (mOffersList == null || index == 0) {
    mOffersList = new ArrayList<Offer>();
}

try {
    mOffersList
        .addAll((Collection<? extends Offer>) gson
        .fromJson(result, collectionType));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: error in result: Nullable object must have
    // a value.
}

if (mOffersList == null || mOffersList.size() == 0) {
    errorMsg.setText("no offers found");
    hadError = true;
} else {
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(
            OffersListActivity.this, mOffersList,
                listType);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // mListView.invalidate();
}
```

The code runs through
`mOffersList = new ArrayList<Offer>();`

then added new elements (only 3 items) and then `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

but in my activity the old list (20 items) is shown and not a new one.

how come?

Comment: because after you call `mOffersList = new `,  you create a new instance of the ArrayList and the adapter still has the old one

Comment: so how can I renew its reference? please write as an answer and I'll vote you

Answer (score -1):

When you want to update an adapter, you can't just update the list of objects: you must update the adapter too.

To do that, I always use this method :

```
void updateAdapter() {
    //Delete the content of the adapter
    adapter.clear();

    //Add new content to the adapter (datas is an arrayList of MyObject)
    for (MyObject obj : datas) {
        adapter.add(obj);
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Hope it'll help

Comment: I have implemented adding items to the same list as paging. Then I only `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and it worked. how come now it's different